Is there a BPF_MAP_LOOKUP_AND_UPDATE_ELEM syscall similar to BPF_MAP_LOOKUP_AND_DELETE_ELEM?
I would like to know if there is a syscall which can be used through libbpf to lookup a map and also update the contents of the map. My use case is to lookup and update an map type of BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY by holding a bpf spin lock.
I thought of changing my map type to BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH and use the BPF_MAP_LOOKUP_AND_DELETE_ELEM.
But in my use case, I don't have to delete the map element but to update the map to an initial value.

I'm guessing you would want that syscall to give you the value before the update and then update that value? If so, no, it doesn't exist today.

No, there is no such thing as BPF_MAP_LOOKUP_AND_UPDATE_ELEM in bpf(2) today. You can see the list of bpf(2) commands at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.9.1/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L922.
